# Transitive dependencies not resolved using gradle 3.0.0

Tags: android, gradle

My own library define in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
}
```

When i include the library into another module in the same project :

```
implementation project(':myLib')
```

support-v4 and okhttp are available in this other module

But when i include myLib into another project via an external dependency

```
implementation 'com.personnal.library:myLib:1.2.4'
```

support-v4 and okhttp are NOT available in this other module while i'm using "api" rather then "implementation"

And I get the error : package android.support.v4.app does not exist

How does myLib dependencies can be exported in the project ?

Here is my library build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://jenkins.greaturl.com:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-lib.pro'
    }
}

configurations {
    deployerJars
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    api "com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1"
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
}


def groupName = 'com.personnal.library'
def versionName = '1.2.4'
def artifactName = 'myLib'

group = groupName
version = versionName
project.archivesBaseName = artifactName

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.deployerJars

            repository(url: 'http://jenkins.greaturl.com:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases')
            snapshotRepository(url: 'http://jenkins.greaturl.com:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots')

            pom.artifactId = artifactName
            pom.groupId = groupName
            pom.version = versionName
        }

    }
}
```

And my project build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.personnal.library:myLib:1.2.4'
}
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: done @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: have you been able to fix this problem? @JérémyThil

Comment: no, still looking for a solution... @roy_lennon

Comment: solution for me was to use android-maven-gradle-plugin on version 2.0 for gradle 4.4 as listed here https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in previous comment, the solution is to upgrade the android-maven-gradle-plugin. This way it can handle the new **api** and **implementation** keywords as lower versions are only aware of **compile** one.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use **transitive = true** while declaring your dependency in other projects, like this:-

```
implementation 'com.personnal.library:myLib:1.2.4',{
 transitive = true
}
```